# When showing a formula I need to see the text horizontal to the value being used...in Excel

Tags: excel, text, formula, equation, evaluate

For example I have in one row pretax income and tax paid, then to the right I have a number representing them, say (c5)`10` and (c7)`13`. Then below I have a ration "effective tax rate" and to the right the inputted equation (`=c5/c7`). When I click show formula  that is what is shown. I want it to show (`=pretax income/tax paid`).

I have tried changing to formula to equal the cells that have the text in them, instead of the values 10 and 10. I need this because I have about 100 ratios that I would like to see the actual inputs in them. Does this make sense?

I notice I can view what I need after that step by evaluating the formulas, I would rather have all the cells just show me the text in the equation at the same time, as I need to use them in another spreadsheet....

Comment: Parsing formula is very complex - I played briefly with a regexp to do this some years ago. Rob Van Gelder has a sample of a [formula tokenise here](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/12/05/formula-tokenizer/) this splits by formula but should be ready adaptable to split via value. I will take a look

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using named ranges, but spaces are not allowed, so you'll have to use something like `PretaxIncome` or `pretax_income` instead of `pretax income`:

- Select cell c5
- click in the address bar, where it says **C5**, and type **pretax_income**
- and so on.

I don't know of a way to get the formulas to change automatically, but once you've named your cells, you can reenter the formulas manually, so, for example, the effective tax rate formula would be **=tax_paid/pretax_income**

Comment: I was hoping to find a macro (which I'm not good with) basically I have it where I can use evaluate and just start doing it that way which maybe a little faster, and go through each one individually... I understand what you are saying, however that would mean I would have to redo the whole sheet, when I may as well start working on my new one in my other worksheet. If they just made an evaluate function...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use only pure Excel, you can't do it directly. Instead, your best option is to just have two independent cells, one that is `=C5 & " / " & C7` to display the formula, and the other that is  `=C5 / C7` to evaluate the formula.

But if you want to evaluate the formula that is displayed (which is what I think you're going for), then you need to use a little VBA. It's easier than it sounds. Just create a new module (usually Alt + F11) and type in this function:

```
Function Eval(ByVal str As String) As String
  Eval = Evaluate(str)
End Function
```

Then on your spreadsheet, keep the same display cell (`=C5 & " / " & C7`) and then evaluate with just `=Eval(D8)`, where `D8` of course is your display cell location.